# How to change background-color of an li tag with hover?

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to change the background-color of an `li` tag with onMouseOver?
I tried it this way, but it won't work:

Code generating the HTML:

```
echo "<a href=".$obj_players->Page." target=_parent>
      <li style=\"background-color:#FFFFFF;\"><span class=\"left\">" . $obj_players->Name . "</span><span class=\"right\">" . $obj_players->Viewers . "</span></li></a>";
```

CSS:

```
#navlist li:hover {
    background-color:#2EA620;
}

#navlist li {
    width:175px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
    font:"Myriad Pro";
    font-size:14px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-color:#333;
}
```

Explanation: I have to declara the background color in the `li` tag because I have different `li` elements with different background colors. And li's are in a `div` with ID navlist.

I also have the problem that I don't want every `li` to change background color with onmouseover, but I will solve this later, since I think I should be able to manage it on my own.

Comment: `#navlist li:hover {
    background-color:#2EA620;
}` doesnt work?

Comment: nope, thats why i asked the question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to remove the `background-color:#FFFFFF` inline, and add that to the css. Then `#navlist li:hover { background-color:#2EA620; }` should work.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jU8Pp/

Comment: ahh xD
Im dumb, thx this also solves my poblem with the lis with other bg colors, since i they dont change than :)

Comment: +1. Note that this is due to [CSS Specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity): inline styles are trump cards. (Whereas `!important` is a joker.)

Comment: Yes, this should solve your issue. Jakob, award the answer as correct.

Comment: Hey, i just found out that this doesnt work properly on Internet Explorer. Anyone an idea how to fix and why??